# What if kc=1 will reactants concentration equals to product concentration

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics, chemical-potential

I read a book, it says if kc=1 it mean reactant concentration equals to product concentration at equilibrium. But I'm wondering that in kc expression we dont just use concentration of an element we raise them to their stoicheometric coefficient(power). Can somebody explain me about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reasoning is correct, $K_c = 1$ doesn't necessarily mean the reactant and product concentrations are equal.

Consider a general reaction:

$$
\sum_ir_i\ce{R}_i \ce{->} \sum_jp_j\ce{P}_j
$$

The equilibrium constant is given by:

$$
K_c = \dfrac{\prod_{j}[\ce{P}_j]_\text{eq}^{p_j}}{\prod_i[{\ce{R}_{i}}]_\text{eq}^{r_i}} \tag{1}\\
\text{if }K_c=1 \text{ then } \dfrac{\prod_{j}[\ce{P}_j]_\text{eq}^{p_j}}{\prod_i[{\ce{R}_{i}}]_\text{eq}^{r_i}} = 1
$$

There is a whole range of concentrations where this can happen.

#### Example

Consider a simple reaction:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{$a$A} &\ce{->} \ce{$b$B}\\
K_c &= \dfrac{\ce{[B]}^b}{\ce{[A]}^a}\\
\text{if }K_c=1 &\text{ then } \ce{[A]}^a=\ce{[B]}^b
\end{align}
$$

I have made an [interactive plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xsdvjue1m9) where you can play around with different values of $a$ and $b$:

[image: concentrations for whic equilibrium constant is equal to 1]

Although concentrations need not be equal, there is **special case**. From equation (1):

$$
\text{if } [\ce{R}_i] = 1 \text{ and } [\ce{P}_j] = 1 \text{ for all }i,j\\
\text{then }K_c = 1
$$

This has been highlighted in the interactive plot as well, where all graphs pass through the point $(1,1)$.